# What is the format of BOOST program options command lines?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I have two switches, 'i' and 'p' that represent IPAddress and Port respectively.

What is the format of the command line?

I have tried:

```
app -i192.168.1.1 -p12345
app -i 192.168.1.1 -p 12345
app -i=192.168.1.1 -p=12345
app -i='192.168.1.1' -p='12345'
app --IPAddress 192.168.1.1 --Port12345
```

My application is having a problem with the IPAddress, and troubleshooting with DDD is unrevealing as I get  for the vm.

Also, the app is running as a daemon, so my cout statements for the IP address and Port are going into oblivion, and printing to the syslog is hindered by the fact that outputting the values is not a const char*.

I plan to use program options for other things as well, but I am in over my head a bit with this.

```
po::options_description config("Configuration");
        config.add_options()
            ("IPAddress,i","IP Address")
            ("Port,p","Port")
             ;
po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, config),
                       vm);

        po::notify(vm);
//...and this is how the values are used

int retval = getaddrinfo((vm["IPAddress"].as< string >()).c_str(),(vm["Port"].as<string>()).c_str(), &hint, &list);
```

Here is a complete program...nothing is printed to the console after 'Values':

```
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

//Using boost program options to read command line and config file data
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    po::options_description config("Configuration");
    config.add_options()
                ("IPAddress,i","IP Address")
                ("Port,p","Port")
                 ;

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, config),vm);
    po::notify(vm);

    cout << "Values\n";

    cout << (vm["IPAddress"].as< string >()).c_str();
    cout << " " << (vm["Port"].as<string>()).c_str();

    return 0;

}
```

Are the inputted values somehow unprintable?

---

Here is gdb output, seems to be be cast problem:

```
28              string address = (vm["IPAddress"].as< string >()).c_str();
(gdb) n
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_any_cast> >'
  what():  boost::bad_any_cast: failed conversion using boost::any_cast

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x0000003afd835935 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Comment: Rather than working directly on your daemon application, why don't you build a standalone test-case for this, in order to understand how to use it in isolation?

Comment: I had thought of that. I think this is a good approach because there are a lot of  complications testing with the current setup.

Comment: post some code please

Comment: @bentaisan: it sounds like you have very limited debugging options this way, so it's probably not a good approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BOOST Program options support the common command line flavours known from Unix systems.
Thus those two should work (they are working for me)

```
app -i 192.168.1.1 -p 12345
app --IPAddress=192.168.1.1 --Port=12345
```

Remarks:

- The documentation with basic tutorial is [at boost.org](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html) (probably you know this already)
- writing a standalone unit test for this is certainly a good advice; boost also provides an easy-to-use test framework for C++

Comment: Can you look a the gdb output and give me a hint? I am searching the web now, but someone here might have a quick solution. Seem like their might be a rtti mismatch. Could it be because I am compiling for a 64-bit target?

Comment: strange... are you sure ther is actually such a parameter? what does vm.count("IPAddress") yield? it should be 1 (one instance of the parameter). If it's zero, then the non-existing result can indeed not be cast into a string